# Unable to deploy Vaadin Java app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, vaadin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run Vaadin 8.0 app on Elastic Beanstalk. I created a War file and upload it to AWS as described here:

https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Amazon+Elastic+Beanstalk+HOWTO

The instructions are helpful but somewhat out of date.

When the code is deployed, the service state switches to "DEGRADED" with the severity of "SEVERE".  When i pulled the logs I saw:

```
------------------------------------- /var/log/nginx/error.log ------------------------------------- 
2017/04/03 21:17:32 29340#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 50.252.224.113, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", 
host: "lowcost-env.minuvpn9c8.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

which I think means there's an nginx proxy server that wants my app to be serving on port 5000, and apparently it isn't. I did not see any other errors in the log. However, I have no idea where to go next.

Help would be hugely appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue with regular java jetty app. Did you ever figure this out on your own?

Comment: No I did not. Sorry. Switched to a standard EC2 instance